# How to disabled a submit button if textarea is empty on submit with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

There should be an easy way of validating this textarea without the use of a plug-in, been trying to check if textarea is empty or has an empty value but I just could not make this work. I have a http://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/f3qQ5/

Hope someone could help.

This is my html:

```
<div class="post-container">
    <form class="reply-form">
        <div class="reply-box">
            <textarea placeholder="Reply box 1..." columns="10" rows="1" name="comment-input"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </div>
        <div class="post-dropdown"></div>
        <div class="post-dropdown-content">
            <div class="post-dropdown-reply">1</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="post-container">
    <form class="reply-form">
        <div class="reply-box">
            <textarea placeholder="Reply box 2..." columns="10" rows="1" name="comment-input"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </div>
        <div class="post-dropdown"></div>
        <div class="post-dropdown-content">
            <div class="post-dropdown-reply hidden">1</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

        ​
```

This is my Js:

```
function gettingReplyVal() {
    $('.reply-form').submit(function(e) {
        var textAreaValue = $(this).find('textarea').val();
        post = $("<div>").addClass("post-dropdown-reply");
        post.html(textAreaValue);
        $(this).find('.post-dropdown-content').prepend(post);
        e.preventDefault();
        $('textarea').val('');
    });
}

gettingReplyVal();​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.reply-form').submit(function(e) {
  if($(this).find('textarea').val().trim() == '')
    return false;
  //submit code here
}
```

You can just use .val(), but I added the trim() just to compensate for spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event keyup() if you want disable the submit button on empty:

```
$('textarea[name=comment-input]').keyup(function(e){
    $(this).parent().find("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
    val = $(this).val().trim();    
    if(val.length > 0){
        $(this).parent().find("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Look demo here http://jsfiddle.net/aanred/NpvsF/.

Comment: personally, I've found [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to be more reliable

Comment: @KevinArthur +1 Oh yep sure, that `.change()` can also be used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this validation

```
if($(this).find('textarea').val()=='')
  return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following jquery script:

```
if($('textarea[name=comment-input]').val().trim()==''){
   $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);  
}

$('textarea[name=comment-input]').keyup(function(){
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
    val = $(this).val().trim();    
    if(val.length > 0){
        $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

its work for me. I wish its also work for you.